# Xml Serialization Error: Unable to cast object of type

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

Can some one help for a strange Serialization issue which I getting in a one environment and  it working fine in all environments..but it failed a particular environment..so I specified as strange here

Code

```
public SomeType[] Deserialize(string xml)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeType[]));
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
    SomeType[] types = (SomeType[])serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
    stringReader.Close();
    return types;
}
```

Serialized XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfSomeType>
  <SomeType>
    <Field1>val</Field1>
    <Field2>val</Field2>
    <Field3>val</Field3>
  </SomeType>
</ArrayOfSomeType>
```

And the exception is:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'SomeType[]' to type 'SomeType'.
>
> at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterSomeType.Write11_SomeType(Object o)

Comment: That error seems to be in the serialize, not the deserialize. Can you show the serialize method?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem, so the error must originate somewhere else. Most likely as @MarcGravell proposes in the Serialization method.

Comment: @user3331475 so what can you tell us about the "particular environment" in which it fails? give us a clue... (and I *still* maintain that the error message shown is from `Serialize`, not `Deserialize`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error here is in the `Serialize` method that you don't show. Your `Deserialize` method works without error. The following `Serialize` method works fine:

```
static string Serialize(SomeType[] values)
{
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeType[]));
        serializer.Serialize(sw, values);
        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

If I had to guess, you have the following:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeType));
```

If you want the *exact* same output without unnecessary namespace alias declarations, change the method to include:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("","");
serializer.Serialize(sw, values, ns);
```

---

Edit showing the current code working fine:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class SomeType
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Field3 { get; set; }
}
public class MyTest
{
    public static SomeType[] Deserialize(string xml)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeType[]));
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
        SomeType[] types = (SomeType[])serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
        stringReader.Close();
        return types;
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<ArrayOfSomeType>
   <SomeType>
      <Field1>val</Field1>
      <Field2>val</Field2>
      <Field3>val</Field3>
   </SomeType>
</ArrayOfSomeType>";
        var items = Deserialize(xml);
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}",
                item.Field1, item.Field2, item.Field3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer..I don't have serialize method..because xml is from external system..and I need typeof(SomeType[]) not typeof(SomeType)

Comment: @user3331475 there is nothing wrong in the code you have shown; it works fine. Can you provide a short but runnable example that illustrates the problem? But I say again: I don't think the error you show is from `Deserialize`... `XmlSerializationWriterSomeType.Write11_SomeType(Object o)` sounds very much like a `Serialize` call. My point with the `typeof(SomeType)` is that *this is what I suspect you are doing wrong in `Serialize`*. I understand that you actually want `SomeType[]`.

Comment: @user3331475 for an example of what I mean by a short but runnable example, see my edit - which shows your `Deserialize` method working just fine with the xml you cite.

Comment: I edited the question..I forgot to specify that it failed in particular environment only..

Comment: Hi..you are right.The issue was in Serialize and not Deserialize because I was checking in wrong place.Issue solved.Thanks